SUMX with filter with a measure
Hoping someone might be able to tell me if this is possible.
I have 2 examples below and while the first it easier to understand the second one is where I get stuck. Below is a table of 7 sites and each has a Total which is made up of GrpA value + GrpB values.

With those 7 sites we can create a
GrpA % using = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[GrpA]),SUM('Table'[Total]))
there is a Nat table similar to the one above and to get the
NatA % we can use = DIVIDE(SUM('Table (2)'[NatA]),SUM('Table (2)'[NatTotal])).
To be able to work out the difference between the GrpA and NatA we could use
A % Var = [GrpA %]-[NatA %]

and while this looks correct if you add the A % Var values together you get 4% instead of 2%
SUMX A Var = SUMX('Table',[A % Var]) will give us the 4% result.

So the second table below has the same values as the first but rather than having the Grp A and B values in separate columns they are combine into 1 column.

So in the second example it looks the same except to get the % we use
A Grp = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Units]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Grp]="A")) 

and then
GrpA % = DIVIDE([A Grp],[Units])

Like the first example we can use A % Var = [GrpA %]-[NatA %] which will give us the 2% but when I try
SUMX A Var = SUMX('Table',[A % Var]) 

to get the 4% all results are 0%.  I realize that this is caused by the GrpA & B values being pulled into one column but would it be possible to achieve the same result at the first example to get the 4% total?

Much appreciated if someone could point me the right direction.

I'm having a difficult time understanding what the question is, can you please explain in a couple sentences what you are trying to solve? Also what is the importance/meaning of SUMX A Var? If we were to take a step back, what business problem are you trying to solve with these additional columns?

Apologies for not being clear. The "A % Var = [GrpA %]-[NatA %]" calculation when it is applied to the Total is 10%-8%=2%.  When you add each row result for "A % Var" together 2%+11%+-3%.... the result will not be 2% but 4%, which is what the "SUMX A Var = SUMX('Table',[A % Var])" will do.  When I try and do a similar calculation in the second  dataset the result of "SUMX A Var" is 0% the only difference is the first dataset has 2 Columns for GrpA and B results and the second dataset has both A & B results in 1 column. How do I add 2%+11%+-3%.... in second dataset to get 4%?

So I found that "SUMX A Var = SUMX(VALUES('Table'[Site]),[GrpA %])-SUMX(VALUES('Table'[Site]),[NatA %])" will give the 4% result I was expecting but is that calculation correct?

I think you need to use SUMX(VALUES(...)) instead of just sumx.
sumx simply adds up all the values in a single column while SUMX(VALUES(...)) is useful when you need to calculate something based on distinct values from another column but still want row-by-row context. The VALUES function returns a table of distinct values, and SUMX iterates over that table.
